# Unable to click on AngularJS Modal dialog popup

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, webdriver

Screenshot of dialog is attached which I want to click on using Selenium Webdriver.

I want to click on the button 'Yes' of this dialog and i've already tried to use Actions and windowshandle but it didn't work and also used 
Alert confirmationAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
but didn't get any success.
[Screenshot of dialog and its HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME9k3.png)

Comment: Do you want to click on the dialog itself or one of its buttons? I assume you want to click on buttons. In the screenshot, it would be vital to open the modal-footer div to see its structure. You could have more precise answers that way or probably you could find the answer yourself.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, [please look at some guidance on how to get the most from this site.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @pcjuzer Yeah i want to click on the button of this dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ngWebDriver (a library built to deal with AngularJs website), you can locate those elements.
Answer is here : https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the this, i think it would work.

Comment: Great 
If it works, please confirm my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use sendkeys unicodes, add one more tab if required

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0020'));
builder.perform();
```